# how to do a button who open a popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

i know that is a "newbie" question but i m totaly new in web dev and i have project in react js.

I try to do a button who open a mini window.

```
  const redirecttest = () =>{
    <Popout url='popout.html' title='Window title' onClosing={this.popupClosed}>
      <div>test</div>
    </Popout>
  }
  console.log(mail);
  return (
    
      <div className="App-header">
        <button type='button' onClick={()=>{redirecttest()}}>Create an area</button>
```

i tried that but my web navigator doesnt like it and say this:

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties


  66 | const redirecttest = () =>{
> 67 |   <Popout url='popout.html' title='Window title' onClosing={this.popupClosed}>
     | ^  68 | 
  69 |   </Popout>
  70 | }


can someone help me please :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a state for the popup visibility, and an event to set between 'open' or 'close', something like:

```
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

function handleVisibility() {
  setOpen(prev => !prev);
}

return (
  <div>
    <button type='button' onClick={handleVisibility}>Create an area</button>
    {isOpen &&
      <Popout url='popout.html' title='Window title'>
        <div>test</div>
      </Popout>
    }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.. Take note that what you put inside the curly brackets{} tells react to evaluate it as a javascript expression. If you want to return a JSX, you use parenthesis ().

```
const redirecttest = () =>(
      <Popout url='popout.html' title='Window title' onClosing={this.popupClosed}>

      </Popout >
 );
```

side note: parenthesis is optional. You only need to wrap your JSX return with parentheses if it's multi-line

`return <div>one line</div>;`

```
return (
    <div>multi-line</div>
    <h1>Yes it is/h1>
);
```